# confused to create a database design for cms

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

i would like to create a dynamic menus, so that admin can easily creates sub menu and its content on it.
I am not so good in database design.  So i thought to ask here   Please help me

---

```
 eg. Java-main menu
     Core Java- sub menu
     Frameworks - Sub menu
        -Struts 1  (Sub menu of 2nd submenu)
        -Struts 2  (Sub menu of 2nd submenu)

 ---------------
```

What i have tried from my mind is :

**DATABASE STRUCTURE**

```
 1)Table: mainmenu
    ---------------
     mainmenu_id   PK(primary key)
     menu_name     ..... 
      content      longtext

    2)Table: submenu
    -------------------
     submenu_id     PK
     mainmenu_id    FK (foreign key refrences mainmenu table)
     submenu_name   ..... 
    content         longtext


    3)Table: thirdsubmenu
    --------------------
      thirdsubmenu_id     PK
      submenu_id          FK (foreign key refrences submenu table)
      thirdsubmenu_name     ........
      content             longtext
```

But i think this is not good approach for creating database, if i have 20 or 30 sub menu of thirsubenu table then i have to create again more table, 
But currently my mind capable of thinking this database.

Please share if you have any better design for this database.

Comment: IMHO this question would be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @pduersteler sir if you know then please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need one table, but you have to add another column, let's call it `parent_id`, to keep the reference with it's parent.

This way, elements with `parent_id`= 0 would be the main menu entries. Elements with `parent_id` > 0 would be submenu entries related to `parent_id`.

Something like this:

```
 Table: menu
---------------
 id   PK(primary key)
 menu_name     ..... 
 content      longtext
 parent_id    int(key to id)
```

This is an example of the data stored in the table:

```
Example
----------------
id | menu_name | content | parent_id
----------------------------------------
1  | main 1    | this is main menu 1 | 0                           <-- First level menu
2  | main 2    | this is main menu 2 | 0                           <-- First level menu  
3  | submenu 1 | this is main menu 1's first submenu's item 1 | 1  <-- Second level menu
4  | submenu 1 | this is main menu 1's first submenu's item 2 | 1  <-- Second level menu
5  | submenu 2 | this is main menu 2's first submenu's item 1 | 2  <-- Second level menu
6  | submenu 1-1 | this is submenu 1's first submenu's item 1 | 3  <-- Third level menu
7  | submenu 1-2 | this is submenu 1's first submenu's item 2 | 3  <-- Third level menu
```

Comment: Is it possible to create many sub menus of third submenu, with the above  table?  is this line you have mentioned above    exaplain my answer? `6  | submenu 1-1 | this is submenu 1's first submenu's item 1 | 3 `

Comment: @Ashutosh yes, table entry with `id` = 6 would be a third level menu's  first item. I'll update the example for clarity.

Comment: New doubt!! So shall i set parentMenuId as a foreign key from my database creating index. Or shall i assume it with out making index and foreign key in the datbase table ? which one will be better?

Comment: @Ashutosh make an index for `parentMenuId` as you would have to query the table against that column.

Comment: MY LAST QUESTION:  I set the index, and  front end GUI is also ready.  i will meke my blog   famous in few years.Would you like to give any additional suggestion   related to my database table?

Comment: @Ashutosh I think it's ok with the table. Maybe you could add and `order` column to have the items ordered as you wish...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can make this with just one level of dependency: the parent menu.

Let's see if I can explain what I mean. Let's say you have the following table:

```
menuId (Int, PK)
parentMenuId (Int, FK)
menuTag (Char)
... (whatever you need)
```

The relationship is, of course, a one-to-many relation with the table itself:

```
menuId (1) --> parentMenuId(∞)
```

You may have realized by now that this is a tree-like structure, so, now what? How do you build your structure?

Start by the top level: The top level menu is the set of all records that don't have a `parentMenuId`. If you decide that top-level menus have a `NULL` parentMenu, then:

```
select *
from tblMenu
where parentMenuId is null;
```

If you decide that top-level menus have a defined value (lets say `0`), simply use this where condition: `where parentMenuId = 0`.

Now, make the recursion magic work. For each `menuId` in your set:

```
select *
from tblMenu
where parentMenuId = ? -- Your menuId goes here
```

This way, you can have everything you need. Of course, when the afore query returns zero rows, you have finished with that menu, and can proceed to the next.

Hope this helps you

Comment: So shall i set parentMenuId as a foreign key from my database creating index. Or shall i assume it with out making index and foreign key in the datbase table ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to create the index... but the foreign key is optional since top-level menus will have a `null` (or `0`) value in the `parentMenuId` field

Comment: As you suggested this database, i created a cms website. But now i am confused to make Sitemap(HTML Ul & li based) using this database table . Above i have updated my question with by writing in detail manner. Please help me to solve this new issue. (my account is currently not active for posting question i.e why i can not post a new question)

Comment: @Danny Now your question is not related to databases, but to HTML (or some other web language). I confess: I don't know anything about web design. I suggest you retag your question or ask another question.

Comment: Thank you sir, its related to php loop.I am trying it & your comments shows that you are a nice & kind person.